# Maxdiff Approach - Claims comparison , how to compare product claims of two different surveys Maxdiff gives Preference shares or count based analysis

Tags: conditional-probability, posterior

My business objective: I want to create a MAX diff approach where I will have multiple surveys my output will be Claims and its Posterior Probability , count of best and worst selection.

For more illustration : Claims can be " reduces water wastage , " Brighter skin", reduces wrinkles" . How can I compare different Survey's claims like for X product claim is Brighter skin" and for Y product " Brighter and reduces sebum on skin" .

Statistically I have posterior probabilities value from each survey and based on that I can rank them. But I cannot directly compare ranks from two different survey for different claims because sample size in both the surveys will be different , rank comparison is not a strong approach . Please suggest any method

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.